Conditionally execute 2nd query/Use Results IF First query returns no results
I have the following query that has an inline view which has two Select statements that are UNIONed together. What I want to do is execute the first query inside this view and if it results in no rows of data being returned Then execute the 2nd query.
If the first query inside the Inline view does return data then I either want to skip executing the 2nd query, or at least filter out any results from it in the outer query. I don't need to execute (or use the results from) the 2nd query IF the first query returns data.
   ( SELECT ESI.item_number, 
            ESI.LONG_DESCRIPTION item_DESCRIPTION,
            TC.TRANSACTION_COST
     FROM    INV_ITEM_SUB_INVENTORIES IOQD
              ,egp_system_items ESI
-----BEGINNING OF INLINE VIEW WITH FIRST QUERY UTILIZING UNION BELOW:----------------------
              , (SELECT * FROM 
                 (SELECT  B.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
                       ,C.SUBINVENTORY_CODE,
                       B.TRANSACTION_COST TRANSACTION_COST
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID, C.SUBINVENTORY_CODE 
        ORDER BY B.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID, B.COST_DATE DESC) rownum1                               
                    ,'' SECONDARY_INVENTORY
                          FROM CST_ITEM_COST_HISTORY_V B,
                               CST_TXN_LAYER_DTLS_V C
                         WHERE 1=1
                           AND B.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID= :p_inv_num                  
                           AND B.TRANSACTION_ID = C.REC_TRXN_ID
                          AND C.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = B.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID 
        ORDER BY B.COST_DATE DESC NULLS LAST
        )
        WHERE rownum1 = 1 AND TRANSACTION_COST IS NOT NULL 
---2ND (CONDITIONAL QUERY BELOW, ONLY RUN/USE DATA IN OUTER QUERY IF FIRST QUERY HAS NO DATA RETURNED---        

UNION 

 SELECT * FROM
  ( SELECT INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,
   SEC.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME  SUBINVENTORY_CODE,
   LN.UNIT_PRICE TRANSACTION_COST            
 , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID , SEC.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME
    ORDER BY INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID, SEC.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME ) rownumber         
     ,INV.SECONDARY_INVENTORY SECONDARY_INVENTORY
   FROM INV_ITEM_SUB_INVENTORIES INV
       ,inv_secondary_inventories SEC 
         ,PO_LINES_ALL LN
        ,PO_HEADERS_ALL HDR
        ,INV_UOM_CONVERSIONS UOM        
                          
    WHERE  SEC.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME = INV.SECONDARY_INVENTORY
     AND SEC.organization_id = INV.organization_id
      AND LN.ITEM_ID = INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID       
      AND HDR.PO_HEADER_ID = LN.PO_HEADER_ID          
      AND UOM.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID(+) = INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
      AND UOM.UOM_CODE(+) = LN.UOM_CODE
      AND INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = :p_inv_num          
   )
    WHERE rownumber = 1 
) TC
----END OF INLINE VIEW (DATA JOINED BELOW IN OUTER QUERY)----------------------------
WHERE IOQD.inventory_item_id = ESI.inventory_item_id
  AND TC.subinventory_code(+) = IOQD.secondary_inventory       )

I don't have the ability to create stored procedures, declare functions or variables, but can use CTE's potentially. Appreciate your assistance with this.
